# $X$ is a completely regular space, and $K,F\subset X$ are like $K$ is compact $F$ is closed and $K\cap F=\emptyset$

Tags: general-topology

$X$ is a completely regular space, I need to show that: If $K,F\subset X$ are like $K$ is compact $F$ is closed and $K\cap F=\emptyset$, then Exist $f:X\rightarrow [0,1]$ continuous with $f[K]\subset\{0\}$ and $f[F]\subset\{1\}$

I could construct functions that separates every point in $K$ and $F$ and I know that $K$ is also closed (compact subset of a $T_2$ space).

Comment: One says that "*compact sets behave like points*", for example, in a regular space a compact set and a disjoint closed set can be separated by disjoint neighborhoods. It is not necessary that $K$ is closed, and the space need not be $T_2$. A completely regular $T_2$-space is also called a Tychonoff space (But some authors include $T_2$ in the definition of completely regular.)

Answer (score 2):

For each $x\in K$ there is a continuous $f_x:X\to[0,1]$ such that $f_x(x)=0$ and $f_x[F]=\{1\}$. Let $U_x=\left\{y\in X:f_x(y)<\frac12\right\}$; $\{U_x:x\in K\}$ is an open cover of $K$, so there is a finite $A\subseteq K$ such that $K\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in A}U_x$. Let $f=\prod_{x\in A}f_x$; then $f:X\to[0,1]$ is continuous, $f[F]=\{1\}$, and $f(y)<\frac12$ for each $y\in K$ (why?).

Now let $g:X\to[0,1]:y\mapsto\max\left\{f(y),\frac12\right\}$. Show that $g$ is continuous, and find a simple modification of $g$ that does what you want.